# invalid literal for int() with base 16: b'??' in python

Tags: python

```
import io
import os, gzip, re

def byte_1gram(byte_code):
   OneByte = [0]*16**2
   for row in byte_code:
       codes = row[:-2].split()[1:]
        # Convert code to 1byte
       OneByteCode = []
       for i in codes:
            if i != '??':
                OneByteCode += [int(i,16)]
        # Calculate the frequency of 1byte
        for i in OneByteCode:
            OneByte[i] += 1
    return OneByte

with open('0ACDbR5M3ZhBJajygTuf.bytes', 'rb') as f:
    print(byte_1gram(f))
```

```
     13         for i in codes:
     14             if i != '??':
---> 15                 OneByteCode += [int(i,16)]
     16
     17         #Calculate the frequency of 1byte
Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b'??'
```

I want to read bytes and extract 1 gram feature but at line # 15 it give me error like invalid literal for int()

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The error message should actually be pretty self-explanatory…

Comment: Change `'??'` to `b'??'`, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you filter by `'??'` - Which is a regular string, but the string you encounter is `b'??'` - Bytes type (only in Python3). They are not equal, so the filter doesn't work.

Change the `'??'` to `b'??'`.

Comment: The check is ( if i != '??':) then it will add it to OneByteCode. i'm not passing ?? to int(i,16)

Comment: Yeah. I think the problem is that you filter by `'??'` and not `b'??'`, which are apparently not the same.

Comment: Great:) I updated the answer to be more informative (and to actually solve your problem)